# Group records by time into clumps - SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, grouping, group-by

I have a table that stores bluetooh detection information. For example:

```
MACaddress         | DetectorID | PollingIntervalStart     | PollingIntervalEnd
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:09.000  | 2012-03-26 16:51:19.000
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:24.000  | 2012-03-26 16:51:28.000
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:35.000  | 2012-03-26 16:51:49.000
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:55.000  | 2012-03-26 16:52:09.000
00:00:00:00:32:11  |    3       | 2012-03-26 17:00:43.000  | 2012-03-26 17:01:19.000
00:00:00:00:20:F1  |    1       | 2012-03-26 17:02:52.000  | 2012-03-26 16:53:02.000
...

00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 19:21:19.000  | 2012-03-26 19:21:48.000
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 19:21:59.000  | 2012-03-26 19:22:51.000
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 19:22:19.000  | 2012-03-26 19:22:31.000
00:00:00:00:20:F1  |    1       | 2012-03-26 20:23:49.000  | 2012-03-26 19:50:30.000
```

The detectorID is the ID of the bluetooth detector that polled the device. As you can see, sometimes a device can linger in the polling radius of the detector so we get a cluster of detection of the same device. What I want to do is group the clusters and take the first detection (meaning `min(DetectionTime)`) of that cluster (say we define a cluster to mean the same device polled multiple time in three minutes). Note that the length of the polling interval for the detectors are not constant. For example for the cluster

```
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:09.000  | 2012-03-26 16:51:19.000 -- take this record
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:24.000  | 2012-03-26 16:51:28.000
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:35.000  | 2012-03-26 16:51:49.000
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:55.000  | 2012-03-26 16:52:09.000
```

I want to get only the first record. After grouping as described above the table should look like:

```
MACaddress         | DetectorID | PollingIntervalStart     | PollingIntervalEnd
00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 16:51:09.000  | 2012-03-26 16:51:19.000
00:00:00:00:32:11  |    3       | 2012-03-26 17:00:43.000  | 2012-03-26 17:01:19.000
00:00:00:00:20:F1  |    1       | 2012-03-26 17:02:52.000  | 2012-03-26 16:53:02.000
...

00:00:00:00:00:01  |    3       | 2012-03-26 19:21:19.000  | 2012-03-26 19:21:48.000
00:00:00:00:20:F1  |    1       | 2012-03-26 20:23:49.000  | 2012-03-26 19:50:30.000
```

I tried using `group by, ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK` and I can't seem to be able to figure it out. I tried using a tally table to make time intervals and join by time interval but that didn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

## Edit

What I mean by "clumps" is that if the same device if detected multiple times in a short period of time then it is considered a clump. I defined that interval as 3 minutes. This interval length is arbitrary, it could have been any number of minutes but I just choose 3 mins. So if a mac address is detected at 3:00:22 and 3:00:34 and 3:01:44 all three detections are considered one clump. If it was detected at 3:00:22 and 3:07:32 it is not a clump.

It has to be the first detection of the clump. If you have code for the last detection of the clump you can post it too. Maybe, I can try to use ROW_NUMBER and descending order by to get the desired output.

## Edit 2

I changed Aaron's code so that the cluster length are no longer constant. The code now just checks for cluster separation. So any detections that are more than 3 mins apart is not considered to be a cluster. This new definition of clusters made the code easier.

Comment: Are you wanting three minutes measured from MIN(PollingIntervalStart)? Is it Start < 3 minutes after that, or End < 3 minutes after that? The text still just says within three minutes of min(DetectionTime) but needs some clarity. Also you have two rows where the end is < start (in the first sample, see rows 6 and 10).

Comment: Also, is it crucial that you get the *first* row in a clump? I have a pretty simple query that gets the *last* row in a clump, but I've exhausted the amount of time I can spend trying to get it to do the reverse.

Comment: I don't think there was any confusion of what you meant by "clumps" - just where you are measuring that. E.g. if one poll started at noon, and ended at 12:01, then another poll started at 12:02:59, and ended at 12:03:01, did that happen "within three minutes"? In other words, do we ignore end time?

Comment: I understand you what you are asking now. The clumping interval length should be measured based on the interval START time. For your example since the clump's earliest start time is 12:00:00 and the last start time is 12:02:59 we would include the last detection in the clumping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by slightly modifying [Aaron Bertrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958509/group-records-by-time-into-clumps-sql-server-2008/19960176#19960176).

Setup the table:

```
DECLARE @d TABLE
(
  MACaddress VARCHAR(32), 
  DetectorID INT, 
  PollingIntervalStart DATETIME2(0), 
  PollingIntervalEnd DATETIME2(0)
);

INSERT @d VALUES
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 16:51:09.000','2012-03-26 16:51:19.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 16:51:24.000','2012-03-26 16:51:28.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 16:51:35.000','2012-03-26 16:51:49.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 16:51:55.000','2012-03-26 16:52:09.000'),
('00:00:00:00:32:11',3,'2012-03-26 17:00:43.000','2012-03-26 17:01:19.000'),
('00:00:00:00:20:F1',1,'2012-03-26 17:02:52.000','2012-03-26 16:53:02.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 19:21:19.000','2012-03-26 19:21:48.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 19:21:59.000','2012-03-26 19:22:51.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 19:22:19.000','2012-03-26 19:22:31.000'),
('00:00:00:00:20:F1',1,'2012-03-26 19:49:49.000','2012-03-26 19:50:30.000');
```

I make two modification to Aaron's code. I made the ordering of the subquery in descending order. And in the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` condition I replaced the `DATEADD` check with `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x2.PollingIntervalStart, x.PollingIntervalStart) < 3`.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY MacAddress, DetectorID ORDER BY PollingIntervalStart DESC) AS RN
    FROM @d
)
select * from x
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM x AS x2 
  WHERE x2.MACaddress = x.MacAddress
  AND x2.DetectorID = x2.DetectorID
  AND x2.rn = x.rn + 1
  -- x2.PollingIntervalStart is always less than x.PollingIntervalStart becasue of x2.rn = x.rn + 1 condition
  -- this works because the cte query is ordered in descending order
  AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x2.PollingIntervalStart, x.PollingIntervalStart) < 3 
)
ORDER BY x.PollingIntervalStart;
```

Thanks Aaron.

Answer (score 2):

Given this sample data (I've corrected your rows where start time > end time, which didn't seem correct):

```
DECLARE @d TABLE
(
  MACaddress VARCHAR(32), 
  DetectorID INT, 
  PollingIntervalStart DATETIME2(0), 
  PollingIntervalEnd DATETIME2(0)
);

INSERT @d VALUES
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 16:51:09.000','2012-03-26 16:51:19.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 16:51:24.000','2012-03-26 16:51:28.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 16:51:35.000','2012-03-26 16:51:49.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 16:51:55.000','2012-03-26 16:52:09.000'),
('00:00:00:00:32:11',3,'2012-03-26 17:00:43.000','2012-03-26 17:01:19.000'),
('00:00:00:00:20:F1',1,'2012-03-26 17:02:52.000','2012-03-26 16:53:02.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 19:21:19.000','2012-03-26 19:21:48.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 19:21:59.000','2012-03-26 19:22:51.000'),
('00:00:00:00:00:01',3,'2012-03-26 19:22:19.000','2012-03-26 19:22:31.000'),
('00:00:00:00:20:F1',1,'2012-03-26 19:49:49.000','2012-03-26 19:50:30.000');
```

This idea gets the last row of the clump. As I said, I think it's certainly possible to get , but I have to move on. This would certainly be easier in SQL Server 2012, which added a slew of ranking functions.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY MacAddress, DetectorID ORDER BY PollingIntervalStart)
  FROM @d
)
SELECT * FROM x 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM x AS x2 
  WHERE x2.MACaddress = x.MacAddress
  AND x2.DetectorID = x2.DetectorID
  AND x2.rn = x.rn + 1
  AND x2.PollingIntervalStart <= DATEADD(MINUTE, 3, x.PollingIntervalStart)
)
ORDER BY x.PollingIntervalStart;
```

Results:

```
MACaddress         DetectorID  PollingIntervalStart  PollingIntervalEnd   rn
-----------------  ----------  --------------------  -------------------  --
00:00:00:00:00:01  3           2012-03-26 16:51:55   2012-03-26 16:52:09  4
00:00:00:00:32:11  3           2012-03-26 17:00:43   2012-03-26 17:01:19  1
00:00:00:00:20:F1  1           2012-03-26 17:02:52   2012-03-26 16:53:02  1
00:00:00:00:00:01  3           2012-03-26 19:22:19   2012-03-26 19:22:31  7
00:00:00:00:20:F1  1           2012-03-26 19:49:49   2012-03-26 19:50:30  2
```

Another idea gets the results you want, but uses a cursor. Personally I think there are cases like this where a cursor is totally acceptable ([also see this discussion on running totals pre-2012](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals), and keep in mind [the caveat that you should use proper cursor options](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)), but others refuse to even look at them. Whether this is practical depends on the size of your data; you should test.

```
DECLARE @newTable TABLE
(
  MACaddress VARCHAR(32), 
  DetectorID INT, 
  PollingIntervalStart DATETIME2(0), 
  PollingIntervalEnd DATETIME2(0)
);

DECLARE @PreviousTime DATETIME2(0) = NULL, @ma VARCHAR(32), @de INT, 
  @st DATETIME2(0), @et DATETIME2(0), @rn INT;

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY MacAddress, DetectorID ORDER BY PollingIntervalStart)
    FROM @d ORDER BY MacAddress, rn;

OPEN c;

FETCH c INTO @ma, @de, @st, @et, @rn;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF @rn = 1 OR (@rn > 1 AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @PreviousTime, @st) > 3)
  BEGIN
    INSERT @newTable SELECT @ma, @de, @st, @et;
  END

  SELECT @PreviousTime = @st;

  FETCH c INTO @ma, @de, @st, @et, @rn;
END

SELECT * FROM @newTable ORDER BY PollingIntervalStart;

CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;
```

Results:

```
MACaddress         DetectorID  PollingIntervalStart  PollingIntervalEnd
-----------------  ----------  --------------------  -------------------
00:00:00:00:00:01  3           2012-03-26 16:51:09   2012-03-26 16:51:19
00:00:00:00:32:11  3           2012-03-26 17:00:43   2012-03-26 17:01:19
00:00:00:00:20:F1  1           2012-03-26 17:02:52   2012-03-26 16:53:02
00:00:00:00:00:01  3           2012-03-26 19:21:19   2012-03-26 19:21:48
00:00:00:00:20:F1  1           2012-03-26 19:49:49   2012-03-26 19:50:30
```